# Balanced Parantheses Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search, backtracking

I've been studying backtracking / DFS algorithms and came across the [balanced parentheses problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses).

This snippet populates an array with all valid parentheses combos based on the value of argument `n`.

```
function findCombo(n, cur, usedOpen, usedClose) {
    if (usedOpen === n && usedClose === n) {
        res.push(cur);
    } 
    if (usedOpen < n) {
        findCombo(n, cur + '(', usedOpen + 1, usedClose );
    }
    if (usedOpen > usedClose && usedClose < n) {
        findCombo(n, cur + ')', usedOpen, usedClose + 1 );
    }
}
```

---

So calling the above with `n = 2`:

```
let res = [];
findCombo(2, "", 0, 0);
console.log(res);
```

correctly prints: `[ '(())', '()()' ]`

And calling it with `n = 3`:

```
let res = [];
findCombo(3, "", 0, 0);
console.log(res);
```

correctly prints: `[ '((()))', '(()())', '(())()', '()(())', '()()()' ]`

---

My question is; how does `findCombo()` continue to iterate after the 1st push to the `res` array? I've traced execution by hand and recursion should stop iterating once `res.push` is executed since at that point `usedOpen = n` and `usedClose = n`.

In other words, I can't see how any subsequent array element gets created, e.g. `'()()'` for `n = 2`.

---

What am I missing?

Comment: There is the unwinding of recursion, and re-entering a second branch of recursion with the second recursive call, which may generate alternatives. I don't know what insight you miss here. Maybe it is that all variables are *local* in scope, and `cur + '('` does not modify the *local* `cur` variable.

Comment: There is no condition for `cur` though. I would expect that once `usedOpen = n` and `usedClose = n` to somehow re-initiate the recursive calls. But that's already happening and that's the part I don't get.

Comment: Just realise that the values for `usedOpen` and `usedClose` are specific per function execution. When execution returns to the caller, these variables are local to **that** execution, and thus the condition `== n` is no longer true for both, and execution can continue to explore other alternatives. I think you miss the concept of local variables, and how each execution has their own set of variables. Or maybe you miss the concept of how executions are *stacked* and the return of the deepest execution will resume the one-but-last one again, ...etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it doesn't recur after.
Here is the recursive calls tree:

- findCombo(2, "", 0, 0)
  - findCombo(2, "(", 1, 0)
    - findCombo(2, "((", 2, 0)
      - findCombo(2, "(()", 2, 1)
        - findCombo(2, "(())", 2, 2)
          - => push_back("(())") //no recursion after
    - findCombo(2, "()", 1, 1)
      - findCombo(2, "()(", 2, 1)
      - findCombo(2, "()()", 2, 2)
      - => push_back("()()") //no recursion after

Comment: Thank you. Same question to the other identical answer; why does the call to `findCombo(2, "()", 1, 1)` happen? At that point `usedOpen` and `usedClosed` are already set to `2`. How do they decrease to a value of `1`?

Comment: @n00b There are up to two recursive calls in each frame. Child calls don't affect parent call frame's values. `findCombo(2, "()", 1, 1)` is the second call that happens in the `findCombo(2, "(", 1, 0)` frame, after the `findCombo(2, "((", 2, 0)` recursive subtree is fully explored. If a parent frame makes a recursive call, that code pauses execution until the child call is totally finished, then continues on to possibly make more recursive calls before it returns and pops the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
 The first level of recursion: the only allowed branch is `if (usedOpen < n) `, so '(' is created
      The second level: `if (usedOpen < n)` is allowed, so `((` is created
           The third level: only the last branch is allowed, so `(()` 
                The fourth level: only the last branch is allowed, so `(())` 
                   Now the fifth level,  res.push(cur) is executed,
                program returns to the fourth level (nothing to do)
            third (nothing to do)

      And second level again: last branch is allowed too, so `()` is created
           The third level: middle branch is allowed, so `()(` 
                The fourth level: only the last branch is allowed, so `()()` 
                    the fifth level,  res.push(cur) is executed
                program returns to upper levels
```

Comment: How does `The second level again` get triggered, though? Hasn't recursion finished iterating after `(())` gets pushed?

Comment: After the first `res.push(cur);` program execution returns  to upper levels until reaches the second level and continues with the last branch

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete expansion of the recursive calls, with the three conditions evaluated (denoted `A`, `B`, `C`).

```
Find(2, '', 0, 0)
. A false
. B true
. . Find(2, '(', 1, 0)
. . . A false
. . . B true
. . . . Find(2, '((', 2, 0)
. . . . . A false
. . . . . B false
. . . . . C true
. . . . . . Find(2, '(()', 2, 1)
. . . . . . . A false
. . . . . . . B false
. . . . . . . C true
. . . . . . . . Find(2, '(())', 2, 2)
. . . . . . . . . A done
. . . C true
. . . . Find(2, '()', 1, 1)
. . . . . A false
. . . . . B true
. . . . . . Find(2, '()(', 2, 1)
. . . . . . . A false
. . . . . . . B false
. . . . . . . C true
. . . . . . . . Find(2, '()()', 2, 2)
. . . . . . . . . A done
. . . . . C false
. C false
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Shouldn't execution finish after `Find(2, '(())', 2, 2)`? I can't see how both `usedOpen` and `usedClosed` decrease from 2 to a value of 1 after `Find(2, '(())', 2, 2)`. At no point do we decrease these variables, so once they equal `n`, execution should stop, no?

Comment: @n00b: you never decrease, you restore to previous values and continue processing on the previous, unfinished level. I have named the three conditions, for clarity. The annotation `done` means that the condition is `true` and recursion is not deepened.

Comment: @n00b: also think that there are two places with `2, 2`, but you can't stop twice, can you ?

Answer (score 0):

It might help you to think of each call to `findCombo` as having a different name; for example, `findCombo_0_0`, `findCombo_1_1`, etc.; because each time it's called, it gets a new stack frame in the computing system. It's not the same `findCombo` call that's doing everything, it's many; they just all have the same execution method, which has been stored under the name, `findCombo`.

`findCombo` parameter values don't decrease or change at all. The execution method called `findCombo` spawns various calls to the same routine, hence we describe it as recursion.

In this particular case, the routine does not provide or use a return value from such a call, rather (in the base case) it pushes a string value to an array defined outside all those calls.